# Add file after generating the installer executable

Tags: nsis

I would if we can add some files(text or executable) to a NSIS installer with a tool(or not) after the package is done.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot really append extra files after the compiler has finished. You can however append a small text string if you need to embed some sort of id/hash/serial number. This data can be read with the [ReadCustomerData function](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/ReadCustomerData) from the NSIS wiki.

You can compile installers on Windows and POSIX based systems so you can build installers anywhere if you absolutely need to add a file that does not exist on your system...